# Cokernel as direct sum of cyclic groups

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices

I am asked to reduce the matrix $ \left( \begin{array}{ccc} 3 & 1 & -4 \\ 2 & -3 & 1 \\ -4 & 6 & -2 \end{array} \right)$ to diagonal form over $\mathbb{Z}$ and then write the cokernel as direct sum of cyclic groups. The problem is that when I computed the Jordan form, I got $\left( \begin{array}{ccc} 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 -\sqrt{34} & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & \sqrt{34} -1 \end{array} \right)$. This isn't a matrix over $\mathbb{Z}$. Is this matrix diagonalizable over $\mathbb{Z}$ or am I misunderstanding something?

It's characteristic polynomial is $x(x^2 + 2x -33)$ over $\mathbb{Z}$ which is also it's minimal polynomial. So as a direct sum of cyclic groups, do I just have $\mathbb{Z}[x] / (x(x^2 + 2x -33))$?.

Comment: The problem is asking to find the Smith Normal Form of your matrix, not the Jordan form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering the matrix as a map $\mathbb{Z}^3\to\mathbb{Z}^3$, you are allowing change of basis in both the domain and codomain (i.e. applying both row and column operations to the matrix (invertible over $\mathbb{Z}$)).  The result will be diagonal and reveal the structure of the quotient.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith_normal_form as noted in the comments.

[I obtained
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
1&0&0\\
0&1&0\\
0&0&44\\
\end{array}
\right)
$$
which gives the cokernel as $\mathbb{Z}/44\mathbb{Z}$.]

Comment: I computed the Smith normal form as $\left( \begin{array}{ccc} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 11 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{array} \right)$. I believe the cokernel is isomorphic to $(\mathbb{Z}/ 11 \mathbb{Z} )\times \mathbb{Z}$. Am I correct in this? Thanks.

Comment: The (3,3) entry should be -2. I originally wrote 2. Sorry about that.